# Apache restart failed after adding OpenID Connect module

Tags: apache, debian, openid-connect, mod-auth-openidc

I use Debian 8.0 running an Apache v.2.4.10 and I try to add the OpenID Connect module named `libapach2-mod-auth-openidc` version 1.6.0.
After installing the module, I enable it with the command: `sudo a2enmod auth_openidc`. This works fine and now I want to restart the Apache server with `sudo service apache2 restart`, which leads me to an error

*"Job for apache2 failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details."*

The result of
`systemctl status apache2.service`
shows an error while starting the server, but no detailed information of the error *(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)*.

And the result of
`journalctl -xn`
tells, that there are no journals.

So if I am disabling the `auth_openidc` module, the Apache server starts again without problems.

Details of the Configuration:

- Apache runs with its default settings. I did not change anything!
- `auth_openidc` module was not changed by me neither at this time!

Can someone explain why Apache with the enabled `auth_openidc` module would not start anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing `libapache2-mod-auth-openidc` you will have to configure some settings before the module can be used successfully. Two of the mandatory settings are `OIDCRedirectURI` and `OIDCCryptoPassphrase`. Most probably you'll also have to configure client credentials for your OpenID Connect provider. You can take a look at the sample configurations at: https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc#openid-connect-sso-with-google-sign-in

Errors/warnings about the missing configuration directives should be displayed in: `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

While we're at it, I would also advise you to use the latest version 1.8.1 from https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/releases